# Error in Bottomnavigationbar Flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

I'm having problems because the IDE tells me there is an error.
1 positional argument expected by 'BottomNavigationBarItem.new', but 0 found.
and this is my code.
I've been trying to solve it for days but I can't find a way.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsTPb.jpg)

Comment: What you have is what it is supposed to look like. Can you share your pubspec.yaml and/or provide more context about what your main.dart file looks like?

Comment: BottomNavigationBarItem.new?.... Why that '.new'?

Comment: Maybe it's smth wrong with ide? Because your code should work as expected. You can try to restart IDE or just use VS Code instead of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the Flutter version is a bit outdated. Try replacing `icon` with `child` and see if that works.